# how to replace values in all column with condition?

Tags: python, pandas

The searched result is all about one column, my question is how to replace values in all column when its vale meet a certain condtion

for example

```
df=
1 20 30
1 4 5
5 8 10

now if the value is larger than 10, replace value to be 10

so my expected result is

df=
1 10 10
1 4 5
5 8 10
```

the one I am thinking to do is like this:

```
mask=df>10
df.loc[mask]=10
```

I got an error of

TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html) if need replace to same value:

```
df = df.clip(upper=10)
print (df)
   0   1   2
0  1  10  10
1  1   4   5
2  5   8  10
```

Your solution should be changed:

```
df[df>10]=10
print (df)
   0   1   2
0  1  10  10
1  1   4   5
2  5   8  10
```

Or with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.mask(df > 10, 10)
print (df)
   0   1   2
0  1  10  10
1  1   4   5
2  5   8  10
```